# MySQL server has gone away when use "executemany" in python code

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

I wrote this function which is run without any error.

```
    def insertRows(self, query,data):
        self.cursor.executemany(query,data)
        self.connection.commit()
```

But, I got the following error when I run my code on another computer for same data.

```
MySQL Error [2006]: MySQL server has gone away
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 157, in <module>
    writePostingLists(lst)
  File "main.py", line 32, in writePostingLists
    mydb.insertKNNIndex(postingLists,tabelName)
  File "/home/pythonCode/Doc2Vec_Annoy/KNN/MySQLRepository.py", line 78, in insertKNNIndex
    self.insertRows(query,inputList)
  File "/home/pythonCode/Doc2Vec_Annoy/KNN/MySQLRepository.py", line 31, in insertRows
    self.connection.rollback()
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

I found out that the problem is the length of list that I give to ***executemany*** function.

The above code is executed without any problem when the length of data is less than 300.

How can I solve this problem?
Is it related to setting of MySQl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option here would be to split up the list into rows of 100 or so. For example:

```
def insertRows(self, query,data, LIST_LENGTH=100):
    START_INDEX = 0
    while data[START_INDEX:START_INDEX+LIST_LENGTH]:
        self.cursor.executemany(query,data[START_INDEX:START_INDEX+LIST_LENGTH])
        START_INDEX += LIST_LENGTH
    self.connection.commit()
```

I suppose mysql (or mysql-python) probably has a maximum character length of the amount of data you can pass to it.

Regarding your error (from https://piwik.org/faq/troubleshooting/faq_183/):

If mysqld gets a packet that is too large or incorrect, it assumes that something has gone wrong with the client and closes the connection. To fix, you can increase the maximal packet size limit `max_allowed_packet` in `my.cnf` file, eg. `set max_allowed_packet = 128M`, then restart your MySQL server: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`.

Comment: I am looking for the reason of get this error on a computer. It is not the solution that I am looking for.